# How to free a webcam after removing the SWF from the DOM (IE)

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer

I have a simple flash application, which displays a user's webcam and a small HTML containing it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Camtest</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mySWFApplication">
        <p>AlternativeContent</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I am using SWFObject to embed my flash application to the DOM

```
swfobject.embedSWF("mySWFApplication.swf", "mySWFApplication", "500", "500", "9.0.0");
```

In the SWF application I select my camera and grant access to it (Webcam LED turns green)

At some point I want to remove the object from the DOM to release the camera:

```
swfobject.removeSWF("myContent");
```

In Chrome and FF everything is fine now. The webcam has been released (LED went dark) and can be used by other applications again.

But in the Internet Explorer the situation is different. The camera is still in use although the div element surrounding the swf has been removed from the DOM.

It looks like that the SWF is still held in the Internet Explorer's memory.

The only thing helping so far is to reload the browser window.

I see two possible solutions to solve this problem in IE:

- Refreshing the page (by forcing a reload)
- Offering an ActionScript/JS bridged method to free the camera

Is there any other way to remove the SWF from the memory without relying on Actionscript or a reload?

Comment: What's wrong with relying on AS/JS to free the camera? (=why are you looking for some other way if that is clearly a good way and very easy to implement)

Comment: Two, maybe three reasons.


1st - When redirecting: User can't reload the page anymore, cause they are on another location

2nd -  When using AS: Due to the asynchronous nature of my application, the SWF might already be not accessible, cause it has been unloaded (it's still in the memory though)


And Reason number 3: Curiosity.

I think this behavior of the IE in this case is very strange. Removing the DOM does help in any other browser, only IE needs a special treatment here. I am using a workaround, not really a solution to my problem.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean you should reload the page/redirect - Imho that should never be done, it's a lame solution almost always. Well yes, the curiosity is always there in my case too but personally I wouldn't be trying to solve this (or at least I wouldn't waste too much time with it). I meant: Before removing it from the DOM you call a function thru ExternalInterface that disables the camera in the SWF - what asynchronous nature could prevent it? Is your app embedded on other sites?

Comment: Yeah defining an external interface method would be a good solution, but I would need to have access to the swf code. Without it, the answer below seems to provide a good mechanism (embedding the swf into an iframe, which can be removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think that the best way to free your cam must come **from flash** itself by adding the action which do that : `your_video_player.attachCamera(null);` and then you can call it using a button or with `ExternalInterface` and javascript.

If you can't touch the swf, you have 2 other ways :

1 - show your swf page into an **iframe** and then you can unload it (the iframe).

2 - you can load your swf page into a **popup**.

Comment: I had not Access to the swf, the trick with the iframe is good. In this case, it might be the best solution for me. So far I have helped me with a simple redirect :)